# connect my netcore app to mongodb using docker-compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I can't seem to connect my app container to the mongodb container

here is the mongo class inside my app

```
public BaseDao(string dbName)
        {
            m_mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            m_mongoDb = m_mongoClient.GetDatabase(dbName);
        }
```

here is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    image: vinnie_app:latest
    depends_on:
      - 'mongodb'
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongodb"
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

and my docker-compose.override

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging
      - NODE_ENV=staging
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:50000
      - MONGODB_URI='mongodb://mongo:27017/'
    ports:
      - 50000:50000
```

I get a 500 error when I try to fetch stuff from the database from the app container. What's the error and how do I connect my app container to the mongodb?? I run the containerized app at http://192.168.99.100:50000/

Answer (score 1):

`m_mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");`
this line should instead read the URI from `MONGODB_URI` environment variable.

`m_mongoClient = new MongoClient(System.getenv("MONGODB_URI"));`

Comment: what if I want to run the app from VS and not docker, it won't work anymore right? I want to be able to run the app from both VS and docker

Comment: `m_mongoClient = new MongoClient(System.getenv("MONGODB_URI") || "mongodb://localhost:27017");`

Comment: `String m_url = System.getEnv("MONGODB_URI"); if (m_url == null) {m_url = `mongodb://localhost:27017"}  `

Comment: @Siyu beat me to a more concise form :)

Comment: System.getenv does not compile. Also Siyu i can't use ||